# Samsung Android device won't go in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb

I have a simple problem, but thus far all of the advice found on this site and others have not helped.

I am trying to debug, through eclipse, on to a samsung device (SCH-R720.)

I have done this before with no problem.  I recently got a replacement device (same make and model, same sd card) and I have yet to successfully get the phone to enter Debug mode.

When it is plugged in, I can see that the USB is connected in my phone's status tray, with the option to copy files to/from my computer (which works fine, by the way) - however, the "Debug mode" message never shows up, and my phone is not seen by eclipse or "adb devices"

Here's what I have tried, in more or less increasing order of obviousness:

In the device "Settings" I have allowed apps from unknown sources, and enabled USB debugging.

I have tried different USB cables, with no change.

I have installed, uninstalled and reinstalled the appropriate USB drivers for my phone on this laptop.  Note that these have already been installed, as I have done lots of debugging on this laptop previously.

I tried clearing the cache of every app installed on my phone, and then simply did a factory reset (not a big hassle since I only got this phone recently.)

In command prompt, I tried "adb devices" and none were listed.  I tried "adb kill-server" and this didn't help at all.

In the Android SDK Manager, I verified that the Google USB Drivers were installed.  They were.  I then reinstalled the Android SDK and re-did all of the above steps, to no avail.

Also I should note that I periodically rebooted both my phone and my computer during these steps listed above.

This is frustrating.  Anyone have this issue before, which wasn't simply caused by not having the drivers installed or something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correct, the computer (windows 7 in my case) remember the autoplay as "copy files to/from my computer". try to alter these settings on your pc.

Comment: +1 for the extensive list of things you've tried. I was having a similar problem, but your list prompted me to try a different cable, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the device vendor in android adb settings file.

First you need to find the device vendor. In windows go to Start->Control Panel->Device Manager->Android Device->open the adb device driver
You will have 3 tabs, 'General','Driver','Details'.

Go to 'Details', select from the combo 'Hardware Ids' and look at the value, it should be something like that:
USB\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY

Hardware vendor is : XXXX

Now you need to add the vendor in the adb settings file:

Its located in:
C:\Users\.android\adb_usb.ini

just insert : 
0xXXXX

at the end of the file.
Save and start adb again(with kill-server)